# Object mode mesh different from Edit mode

Tags: modeling

[image]No modifiers, no shape keys or anything; it's just the starting cube. It's not showing insets I made. [image]

[image]

Comment: As a guess try to unhide everything in Edit mode and see if there's another similar column hidden which obscures the more detailed one

Comment: Could you please send a .blend file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hidden polygons
Press ALT + H to unhide ande then, delete all.

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: How does that even happen lol. Well thank you